# Rewrite URL after Symfony rewrites rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2, url, symfony

The goal is to add the locale "en" at the beginning of the URLs which doesn't have it.

Example

```
https://example.com/document/file.php
```

Becomes

```
https://example.com/en/document/file.php
```

The following rule works fine alone:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/
RewriteRule ^(.*) /en/$1 [R=302,L]
```

The thing is that I'm stucked in rewriting the URL after the Symfony rules.

- Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]`
- Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by Apache

  `RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`
- Remove app.php from the URL

  `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteRule ^app_pre_prod\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]`
- Add the requested page to the index (exemple index.php/login)

  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]`

The best result I have is: nothing changes.

Or by deactivating the third rule and removing the flag `[L]` of the last one, the following result:

```
https://example.com/en/app.php/document/file.php
```

Comment: "after the Symfony rules" - why _after_ the Symfony rules? That doesn't appear to make sense (and would indeed be a problem). This would seem to be an external redirect and should go at the top of the file. Or, don't redirect at all and default to `en` in your application?

Comment: Or are these URLs that you need to inject `/en` nothing to do with Symfony, ie. entirely outside of the framework? (Although you still wouldn't do this _after_ the Symfony rules.)

Comment: You're right, adding `/en` has nothing to do with Symfony. I was assuming that it should goes after the Symfony rewrite rules but I was probably wrong according to your comment. In the other hand, placing the locale rewrite before gives the last result of the post.

Comment: By default `/en` is added in the application. The thing is that this locale is new and all the links that have been shared before doesn't have it. In a matter of SEO and ressource availabilty we must rewrite these old URLs.